# skb_dst() returns NULL

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to write a virtual netdevice driver on linux kernel 3.3.2. Some features of my driver need the route info when transmitting packets, so I use function skb_dst(struct sk_buff *) to get the dst_entry pointer. But whatever I do, wherever I ping, whenever I try, **skb_dst() always returns NULL**. I don't know why, and the bug confused me for more than a week. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason! It's because of a flag added to kernel: `IFF_XMIT_DST_RELEASE`, if a virtual device is allocated with the flag set to `0`, the kernel will drop the routing information when sending the `sk_buff` to the device. Thanks for Kristof Provost's reply all the same and sorry for ending the question so late.

Answer (score 1):

Ping uses RAW sockets. They probably bypass part of the routing infrastructure.

Try looking at `raw_send_hdrinc` and `raw_sendmsg` in `net/ipv4/raw.c`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, add `dev->priv_flags &= ~IFF_XMIT_DST_RELEASE;` to setup function

Comment: Don't you think this can be a comment to the previous answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have 50 reputation to comment the previous one. @GiulioCaccin